# How to upgrade chaincode in Hyperledger Fabric consortium on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)

Tags: azure-aks, hyperledger-chaincode, azure-blockchain-workbench, azure-blockchain-service

I set up hyperledger fabric on [Hyperledger Fabric consortium on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/blockchain/templates/hyperledger-fabric-consortium-azure-kubernetes-service)
. After successfull installation, I made some changes in this path (samples/chaincode/src/chaincode_example02/go/chaincode_example02.go). Now I want to update this chaincode changes into the network. I have referred [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/commands/peerchaincode.html). I seems like azure-cli does not has upgrade command. Can someone help me to upgrade chaincode using azhlfTool.
Here is available command,

```
sa@Azure:~/azhlfTool$ ./azhlf chaincode help
./azhlf chaincode <command>

Chaincode commands

Commands:
  ./azhlf chaincode install      Installs chaincode to the peers. Should be called with peer.
  ./azhlf chaincode instantiate  Instantiate chaincode to the application channel. Should be called with peer.
  ./azhlf chaincode invoke       Invoke chaincode on the application channel. Should be called with peer.
  ./azhlf chaincode query        Query chaincode on the application channel. Should be called with peer.

Not enough non-option arguments: got 0, need at least 1
```

Comment: Thanks Gurunath! We have known this requirement. AKS HLF is for experiencing template deployments of HLF and the azhlfTool code with it has been open-sourced for that purpose. One way is you can modify the azhlfTool in way you wish to use it, or you can make use of a local fabric-tools container (as a peer CLI) for performing all the available native HLF operations.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the source code of azhlf chaincode on [github](https://github.com/Azure/Hyperledger-Fabric-on-Azure-Kubernetes-Service/blob/7074c2905bb948b90d129352403131e6d30537c2/azhlfTool/commandHandlers/chaincode-ops.ts), it only supports above listed operations. You will have to raise a feature request to add upgrade into azhftools command in order to use it directly.